# verilog assignment for wires

Tags: verilog

I have just started using Verilog and I was wondering if there is a way to do the following:

If I have three two bit wires where testmux connects to muxt in its index one bit and muxt connects to muxt2 in its index one bit, is there a way to access the "1" bit within muxt2 through an assignment based on only testmux? I naively tried using the very last line in the snippet of code below, but it does not seem to work, even with parentheses. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
output test;
  wire [1:0] testmux = {muxt,1'b0};
  wire [1:0] muxt = {muxt2,1'b0};
  wire [1:0] muxt2 = {1'b1,1'b0};
  assign test = testmux[1][1][1];
```

[Crude Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Ydw.png)

Comment: The expression `testmux[1][1][1]` would access index (1,1,1) from a 3D array. `testmux` is not a 3D array, it is a 1D (packed) array. It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. (For example, the expression `{muxt,1'b0}` is 3 bits wide - `|  muxt[1]  |  muxt[0]  |  1'b0  |`.) Perhaps you could draw a diagram or add some ASCII art?

Comment: I added a quick diagram to see if I could better express my goal. I see now that the expression you mentioned does actually have 3 bits, so my set up must be incorrect for what I am trying to achieve. What I was trying to achieve with the expression in the last line was to basically have (testmux[1]) be the equivalent to muxt. Then I would have muxt[1][1], which I had hoped would be equivalent to muxt2[1], evaluating to "1". I see now that my way of going about that is completely wrong, so thank you.

Comment: These boxes on your diagram cannot be (2 input) muxes: muxes have a select input to control which of the other two inputs should drive the output. There are no select inputs in your diagram or in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with my drawing. My idea was to have the [1][1][1] in the expression testmux[1][1][1] be the selects of each of the boxes that would be muxes. With this in mind, the drawing should actually have the 1 on top and the 0 on bottom for each box. In my mind, the expression testmux[1] would be the equivalent of having a "1" bit as the select of testmux which would control the output connected to muxt.

Answer (score 0):

The there is no way to do it the way you want. You really created a hierarchical wiring, but the array access is only allowed on a flat wire. There is no way in verilog to do such a hierarchical expressions.

If i understand your intent correctly, the only  need to access the upper bit of the muxt2. BTW, you also need to change the order of declarations. The wires must be declared before they are used.

```
output test;

wire [1:0] muxt2 = {1'b1,1'b0};
wire [1:0] muxt = {muxt2,1'b0};
wire [1:0] testmux = {muxt,1'b0};

assign test = muxt2[1];
```